# WMS from password protected portal not loading in Leaflet on R - works fine in QGIS

Tags: r, leaflet, gis, basic-authentication, wms

After creating a few WMS, I have tried loading them in R to display them on a map but sadly the leaflet map doesn't show them - only the backdrop does. I had no issue displaying them in QGIS with authentication, etc.

The layers contained in the WMS are all rasters from tiff files that have a global coverage, CRS is EPSG:3857.

I suspect that the authorisation is causing some problems. I have tried to either add the credentials as part of the WMS link, as options in the leaflet map code or in add_headers.

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you. I cannot provide the original links due to the related data being unpublished, but I have retained structure of links and code - and I would like to stress again that the WMS and the authentication works fine in QGIS.

```
# alternative 1
url_path <- "https://datasets.unim.global/maps/a3910gki-edpo-09f1-836e-e6ce1867b78e?
request=getCapabilities&service=WMS&cache=false&username=MY_USER&password=MYPASS"

### Note that I have also tried to call url_path with a shorter url but still no luck:
# https://datasets.unim.global/maps/a3910gki-edpo-09f1-836e-e6ce1867b78e?

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addWMSTiles(url_path,
              layers = 'alba',
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png",transparent = TRUE))


# alternative 2
url_path <- "https://datasets.unim.global/maps/a3910gki-edpo-09f1-836e-e6ce1867b78e?
request=getCapabilities&service=WMS&cache=false&"

username <-'MY_USER'
password<- 'MYPASS'

auth_headers <- add_headers(Authorization = paste("Basic", enc2utf8(paste(username, ":", password))))

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addWMSTiles(url_path,
              layers = 'alba',
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png",transparent = TRUE, headers = auth_headers))
```

Comment: did you manage to find an solution for this? I am in the same boat and stuck in the middle of ocean

Comment: @Avais hey unfortunately nothing as of yet :( I spoke with multiple people (senior and so) and nobody could find a solution to this, leaflet don't seem to have this option I am afraid (what a waste of time!).
If it's of any help, my alternative solution is to move the all the raster files that were converted to WMS to an SQL database (as raster files) and access them from R by querying this database.